# JsonObject.put creates a new node inside my JsonObject, how do I make it search for the node and THEN replace the value?

Tags: java, android, json, node.js

I have a custom JsonOBject implementation where it has this method :

```
public TestJsonNode change(String nodeName, Object newValue) throws JSONException, JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        String jsonString = jsonData.toString();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        jsonObject.put(nodeName, newValue);
        JsonNode newJsonData = (new ObjectMapper()).readTree(jsonObject.toString());
        jsonData = newJsonData;
        return this;
 }
```

Now I have this example JSON :

```
{
  "result": {
    "one": 5030,
    "two": 9999,
    "three": 4,
    "four": 0,
    "five": 50,
    "six": 503,
    "seven_array": {
      "id": 4,
      "quantity": 50,
      "name": "100% Energy Potion"
    },
    "eight": 50,
    "nine": 5,
    "ten": 4000,
    "eleven": 400,
    "twelve": 150,
    "thirteen": 9999
  },
  "fourteen": true,
  "fifteen": true
}
```

And I try to use my method like this

```
TestJsonNode jsonNode = new TestJsonNode(jsonStringExample);
jsonNode.change("eight", 0);
```

What I get happens then is that the `"eight"` node is created anew and `put` alongside the values `"fourteen"` and `"fifteen"` like this :

```
{
  "result": {
    "one": 5030,
    "two": 9999,
    "three": 4,
    "four": 0,
    "five": 50,
    "six": 503,
    "seven_array": {
      "id": 4,
      "quantity": 50,
      "name": "100% Energy Potion"
    },
    "eight": 50,
    "nine": 5,
    "ten": 4000,
    "eleven": 400,
    "twelve": 150,
    "thirteen": 9999
  },
  "eight": 0,
  "fourteen": true,
  "fifteen": true
}
```

Comment: Note that `ObjectMapper` is thread safe and stateless after construction. Don't create a new one on every call. Store a single instance somewhere where it's accessible and reuse it by everyone.

Comment: What if both your root JSON object and the one named `result` contained a pair named `eight`? (What you're asking for is just not how JSON works. Find the JSON object with the pair that you want to change and change it.)